# Every element in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[5]{2}]$ has a multiple in $\mathbb{Q}_+[\sqrt[5]{2}]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I need help understanding this theorem.
My professor gave it to me and I can't find anything about it online. The topic is Algebraic numerical fields (I couldn't find the tag in the list of topics).

Let $a= \sqrt[5]{2}$, that is, $a^5 = 2$.

Consider the algebraic number field 
$$F =  \mathbb Q[a] = \{\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 a + \alpha_2a^2 + \alpha_3a^3 +\alpha_4a^4 \mid \alpha_i \in  \mathbb Q\}$$
(check that F is a subfield of R)

and
$$P = \{\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 a + \alpha_2a^2 + \alpha_3a^3 +\alpha_4a^4\mid \alpha_i \in \mathbb{Q}_+\}.$$ 
P is a subfield of F

Prove the theorem: for any $f \in F$, there exists a $g \in P$ such that $fg \in P$ or $-fg ∈ P$.

I tried solving this on my own but I'm failing to even start. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: What does $\mathbb{Q}_{+}$ mean?  I have seen people use this kind of notations to mean "positive rational numbers" and some use it to mean "nonnegative rational numbers."

Comment: It seems to be the case that, for $f\in F$ such that $f$ is a positive real number, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $$(1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4)^n\,f=k_0+k_1a+k_2a^2+k_3a^3+k_4a^4$$ for some positive rational numbers $k_0,k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4$.

Comment: Can you please explain your logic and what does your comment mean? I'm completely lost on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

A variation on Batominovski's comment:

First note that there are rational numbers $r$ arbitrarily close to $a$.

Then inspect the coefficients of $1, a,a^2,a^3\text{ en } a^4$ for $(1+\frac ar+\frac{a^2}{r^2}+\frac{a^3}{r^3}+\frac{a^4}{r^4})\,f$ and  their limits as $r\to a$.